# What's the number passed when Windows opens a screensaver's settings?

Tags: delphi, windows-screensaver

I'm writing a screensaver, and checked for the parameter `/c` to see if the screensaver has to be started, or the settings windows should be shown.

[image]

I found that the actual parameter passed is `/c` followed by a number, i.c. `3805726`, the full argument is

```
/c:3805726
```

What does this number mean?

Comment: try asking in "the old new thing" blog.  But please present a VERBATIM command line, because from your current description the switch and number seem to be totally unrelated.

Personally I would try to look into all windows on the desktop to see if it match some handle and use process explorer to see if it matches handle to some registry key or file or folder

Comment: that's why I downvoted the question and upvoted the answer which fully reflect the documentation. The qustion states "*`/c` followed by a number*" but in the comment below is followed by a colon: the full cmd line would be indeed appreciated

Comment: @fantaghirocco I clarified my question

Comment: @fanta - The gist of the question is that there's a number OP want explained. Upvoted to cancel the downvote.

Comment: @stevenvh I've already removed the downvote and I've understood the q :D Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the `/c` parameter does not specify a number, the screensaver is expected to display its configuration dialog modal to the `HWND` returned by `GetForegroundWindow()` (the "Screen Saver Settings" window).

If the `/c` parameter specifies a number (either in `/c:###` or `/c ###` format), the number represents an `HWND` (similar to the `/p` parameter) that the screensaver is expected to display its configuration dialog modal to.  On my Win7 machine, that `HWND` contains the contents of the "Screen Saver" tab on the "Screen Saver Settings" window.